# How to install Visual Studio 2008 and MS SQL Server 2008 in Ubuntu?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ubuntu, installation

I would like to install Visual Studio 2008 and MS SQL Server 2008 on Ubuntu OS which I have in my PC.

Comment: I only wrote that comment because I just couldn't comprehend installing VS on Ubuntu.

Comment: Installing Visual Studio on wine is a benefit if you are developing projects say in mono, and want to develop cross-platform code that works well, and verify that it does and are like me, who doesn't have a seperate machine to do it on and hate how slow VM runs, at this time, Wine is doing pretty good for Ubuntu i386 (stick to LTS) but NOT x64, ive found x64 stuff is crap still for the most part, if you use x64 make SURE that you install wine:i386 and not just "wine" which is of course going to default to x64 if you dont specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wine is great, but using it for either Visual Studio or MS SQL Server is probably pushing it.  Both are behemoths that tend (especially VS) to use the latest MS APIs.  More to the point, both [VS](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) and [MSSQL](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=application&sTitle=Browse+Applications&iItemsPerPage=25&iPage=1&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true) are listed as Garbage in Wine's db, meaning compatibility is very poor.

I would recommend you take a serious look at the available tools on GNU/Linux, such as MonoDevelop, Mono, Eclipse, MySQL, etc.  You can use cross-platform build technologies, such as nant to build the same apps on both platforms.

If that isn't an option, then you will have to resort to virtualization, as noted by sean.

Comment: Well, then there is only VM then. Poor Ubuntu.

Comment: Vicheanak, it's really poor Microsoft.  Most of what people think of as "Linux" apps (Eclipse, GIMP, gcc, Apache, MySQL, and more) are actually cross-platform, while MS shows little interest in reciprocating.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429/which-desktop-virtualization-software-runs-most-smoothly) might help you.  Visual Studio and SQL Server are for Windows OS variants.  You'll need some sort of VM to run on Ubuntu.

Comment: +1. I use VMWare Player for this but any of the reputable VMs should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some sort of Windows OS disks available to you (XP / Vista / 2008), then you could consider installing Windows under [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org), and installing your software inside that VM. That used to work really well for me when I was still on Ubuntu.

Comment: I found virtualbox very useful to get up and running quickly to have a Win VM in Ubuntu, without having to spend too much time configuring the VM host (as opposed to vmware).

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing using Visual Studio in Ubuntu since version 10.04, and there is a solution, although I would recommend that you run the 64 bit version of Ubuntu and have at least 4Gb of ram available.

Install the latest version of VirtualBox (download from the website, rather than using the ubuntu repository), and install Windows as a virtual machine. You need to allocate a virtual disk and then, when the virtual machine starts for the first time, either install Windows from a CD/DVD, or select a CD image to use within VirtualBox.

You will also see, with the later versions of VirtualBox, something called "seamless mode". This essential hides the virtual machine, so that instead of running in a window, it will integrate with the Ubuntu desktop. That way, you can run Visual Studio in what looks to be native to Ubuntu.

I have tried both VMWare Player and VirtualBox and found VirtualBox to be better for my setup. Although VMWare Player has something called VMWare tools, which provides an API layer to better translate Windows calls to your video card, this can be temperamental if you're using an ATI card (speaking from experience with a Mobility Radeon HD 4600). Nvidia provide much better driver support in Linux than ATI do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to simply dual boot to write your .net code. It will put your hardware to better use, and you will be able to focus more since all the programs on which you waste your time will be on the linux side :D (at least that's the upside for me)

Answer (score 0):

To use Visual Studio 2008 and MS SQL Server 2008 in any Linux..

Just try sharpdevelop: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/